# I want an OOP solution to when I click a div something to happen

Tags: javascript, arrays, class, oop

I just want to make this code OOP js

```
document.querySelectorAll('.yahtzee_die').forEach(function(e) {
    e.addEventListener('click', function() {
        if (e.classList.contains('clicked')) {
            e.classList.remove('clicked');
        }
        else if(document.querySelectorAll('.clicked').length < 4) {
            e.classList.add('clicked');
        }
    });
});
```

This is what I tired

```
const yahtzee_die = document.querySelectorAll("yahtzee_die");

class Dicee{
    selected(element){
        if (element.classList.contains('clicked')) {
            element.classList.remove('clicked');
        }
        else if(document.querySelectorAll('.clicked').length < 4) {
            element.classList.add('clicked');
        }
    }    
}


let controller = new Dicee();
yahtzee_die.forEach(dice => {
    dice.addEventListener('click', () => {
        controller.selected(dice);
    });
});
```

It does not give me errors but it doesn't execute like the first code. I want to know why!

Comment: your query selector is different, you should prepend a dot in the second code example (before `yahtzee_die`)

Comment: Notice that your first code already is OOP: every time there's a `.` in the code you are using an object! There's no good reason to create a `class Dicee` controller unless it would have a) multiple instances or b) local state of its own. You are storing all of your state in the DOM currently. Fix *that* if you want to improve your code - make a model class for the dice, store their selection state as a boolean property, have an array of them in your game.